# How can I make echo or printf in shell ignore a double backslash (\\) and print it as I see it

Tags: linux, shell, printf, ascii, echo

I'm trying to enter some ascii word art into my shell script and I'm using two backslashes (\\) together I want    echo    or    printf    to print both these backslashes together. Is there something I can put after    echo    or    printf   to make them literally print every character within the double quotes (")?

for example I want:

```
echo -something "
     __      __  __      __
      \\    //    \\    //
       \\  //      \\  //
        \\//        \\//
"
```

to print

```
     __      __  __      __
      \\    //    \\    //
       \\  //      \\  //
        \\//        \\//
```

Exactly how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes are your friend; backslash is just an ordinary character inside a single-quoted string. So is every other character except single-quote itself.

```
echo '
     __      __  __      __
      \\    //    \\    //
       \\  //      \\  //
        \\//        \\//
'
```

If you needed single quotes in the single-quoted output, you have to write the sequence `'\''` to get the single quote:

```
echo '"single quotes" ('\'') are harder than "backslashes" (\)'
```

where I included double quotes and backslashes to make it harder to use double quotes around the string.  However, you could also write:

```
echo "\"single quotes\" (') are harder than \"backslashes\" (\\)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS X. On Mac you need `printf %s '...' `

Comment: @asmaier: What doesn't work on which version of macOS, and which shell are you using? Both the final commands produce `"single quotes" (') are harder than "backslashes" (\)` using Bash on my Mac (tested with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 just now). The first one also produces the output I expect. Are you perchance using macOS Catalina and `zsh`? I forget which version applied when I wrote this 4½ years or so ago — but I would have been using Bash then, too. I'd expect it to work with any POSIX-compliant shell (or more-or-less compliant shell). It might not work with a C shell derivative (e.g. `tcsh`).

Comment: In your first command echo on Mac will not return the double backslash, but instead will produce a single backslash.

Comment: Odd.   On my Mac, I get the double backslashes as required by POSIX.  You’ve not identified which version of macOS you’re using, nor which shell.  Until you identify those as I did, your claim is unsubstantiated and contradicted by what I see on my MacBook Pro.  YMMV.  I’m not aware of using any odd settings to modify the behaviour of Bash.  If you run `shopt-s`, does `xpg_echo` show as `on`?

Comment: With `zsh` (zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) on Mac I have a problem with `echo`. But you are right, it doesn't happen when using `bash` .

Comment: Ahah — so `zsh` _is_ the culprit (or, at least, the source of differences and difficulties). Unfortunately, this is the sort of thing that brings tears to the eyes, especially as Apple has made `zsh` the default (preferred) shell with Catalina 10.15.  I believe there are licencing issues with Bash 4.x and 5.x (it now uses GPL v3) that prevent Apple from upgrading Bash from 3.2.57(1). Presumably `zsh` doesn't have the same problem.  But there are enough differences in `zsh` that it doesn't inspire me.  I will probably end up building and using Bash 5.x etc.